# No warning when I use "self" in block

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

I have been always getting warning when trying to use "self" in blocks until this:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakself = self;
[self.segmControl setSegmPosition:^(int position) {
    [weakself.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.view.size.width*position, 0, weakself.view.size.width, weakself.view.size.height-10) animated:YES];

[weakself.segmControl setScrlView:position];
}];
[self.view addSubview:self.segmControl];
```

[image]

Comment: You should post actual code rather than a screen shot

Comment: @Paulw11 How can I show an absence of a warning with an "actual code"?

Comment: You could highlight the line in question with a comment or you could include the code and the screen shot

Comment: @Edward I think he means you should copy and paste the text of the code as text rather than (or as well as) a screenshot.

Comment: Because you say "I have been always getting warning when trying to use "self" in blocks until this: " tells us where you are expecting there to be an error, but don't see one. I edited it to show you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not always a problem to use `self` in a block; the warning is issued if the compiler thinks that doing so will lead to a circular reference. That is, using `self` in a block causes the block to hold on to the object referenced by `self`; that's no big deal unless the `self` object also holds a strong reference to the block.

The code you posted is of the form:

```
[self.foo method:^{ [self bar]; }]
```

That's not obviously a problem. The block is going to capture `self`, but then you are passing it to the method on an object that `self` is only holding a reference to. It *might* create a circular reference, but it might not. We'd have to know what happens inside the method, which is difficult for the compiler to know for certain; even if you have the source code to method `method:` the compiler can't be certain you're calling that implementation until runtime.

Contrast that with:

```
self.foo = ^{ [self bar]; }
```

In that case, the block is capturing `self` and is holding on to a strong reference to the block (assuming `foo` is defined as `@property (strong)`). In this case the compiler can be more-or-less certain that you are creating a circular reference here, and so it will warn you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, this particular "self" was causing a great memory leak, but now i know why.

Comment: @Edward That's not surprising. Just because nobody shouts "duck!" doesn't mean you're not about to get hit by a ball. :-)

Comment: Or hit by a duck for that matter. :) (Good answer. Voted.)

Comment: @benzado Oh yes, indeed :D